# Python Combinations and product

Tags: python, list, combinations, product, python-itertools

I have a list of dataframes columns:

```
L=[AA ,  AS  ,  AD  , BB  , BC  , CD ,  CF,CG ]
```

and I need all combinations of items, in no particular order.

However, I can only have one name starting with A in each combination BUT I can have multiple names starting with C or none.

Regarding B's I must have at least 1 B but could have more

So I need all combinations of

```
A=[AA,AS,AD] #only one of these
B=[BB,BC]  #at least one of these
all_others=[CD,CF,CG]  #All, 1, 2 or none of these
```

So far I have this code;

```
from itertools import product

for choices in product(['AA','AS','AD',None],['BB', 'BC', None], ['CD','CF', None],):
    print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))
```

This works, however, it only allows for one value starting with C, but I want to `product` all combinations of C. Can anyone see a good edit I can make?

To summarise; I need all combinations of the names in the list. With the one rule, that you can't have more than 1 variable starting with A and more than one variable starting with B

Comment: It's really hard to follow what your output should be.

Comment: Hey it should be all combinations of the names in the list. With the one rule, that you can't have more than 1 variable starting with A and more than one variable starting with B. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more robust/general way of doing the sort of thing you want.  I start by defining a helper function:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain, product

def subsets_of_length(s, lengths):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s,l) for l in lengths)
```

It produces the following output:

```
>>>> list(subsets_of_length(['a','b','c'], range(2,4)))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]

>>>> list(subsets_of_length(['d','e'], range(0,2)))
[(), ('d',), ('e',)]
```

Now we want to combine two or more subsets as follows

```
>>>> for choices in product(
         subsets_of_length(['a','b','c'], range(2,4)),
         subsets_of_length(['d','e'], range(0,2)),
     ):
         print(' '.join(str(subset) for subset in choices))

('a', 'b') ()
('a', 'b') ('d',)
('a', 'b') ('e',)
('a', 'c') ()
('a', 'c') ('d',)
('a', 'c') ('e',)
('b', 'c') ()
('b', 'c') ('d',)
('b', 'c') ('e',)
('a', 'b', 'c') ()
('a', 'b', 'c') ('d',)
('a', 'b', 'c') ('e',)
```

But we want to chain these tuples together.  Thus we should do

```
>>>> for choices in map(chain.from_iterable,product(
         subsets_of_length(['a','b','c'], range(2,4)),
         subsets_of_length(['d','e'], range(0,2)),
     )):
         print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))

a b
a b d
a b e
a c
a c d
a c e
b c
b c d
b c e
a b c
a b c d
a b c e
```

The code for the case of your edited question would be:

```
for choices in map(chain.from_iterable,product(
    subsets_of_length(['AA','AS','AD'], [1]),       #only one of these
    subsets_of_length(['BB','BC'], [1,2]),          #at least one of these
    subsets_of_length(['CD','CF','CG'], [0,1,2,3]), #All, 1, 2 or none of these
)):
    print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, very kind. I'll try and digest / apply your code, and let you know if it works. Looks very promising. Cheers,

Comment: Worked great. Very impressive

Comment: On that last one can I write

Comment: subsets_of_length(['CD','CF','CG'], [0:3]?

Comment: Glad it worked!
I think I see what you're getting at with wanting to use a selector.  It doesn't seem to fit here since we're selecting lengths, which are just ranges of integers.  If you really wanted, you could write `range(100)[0:3]`.  But this is equivalent to `range(3)`, which gives `[0,1,2]`.  Note that thanks to Python's screwy indexing convention, we're missing `3` at the end, so we need `range(4)` instead.  That's why for small lists, I prefer to write them out explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of your `for` loop:

```
for choices in itertools.product(['AA','AS','AD',None],['BB', 'BC', None],[' '.join(k) for j in list(itertools.combinations(['CD','CF'],i) for i in range(3)) for k in j]):
    # do what you need
```

output for choices using `print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))` is :

```
AA BB
AA BB CD
AA BB CF
AA BB CD CF
AA BC
AA BC CD
AA BC CF
AA BC CD CF
AA
AA CD
AA CF
AA CD CF
AS BB
AS BB CD
AS BB CF
AS BB CD CF
AS BC
AS BC CD
AS BC CF
AS BC CD CF
AS
AS CD
AS CF
AS CD CF
AD BB
AD BB CD
AD BB CF
AD BB CD CF
AD BC
AD BC CD
AD BC CF
AD BC CD CF
AD
AD CD
AD CF
AD CD CF
BB
BB CD
BB CF
BB CD CF
BC
BC CD
BC CF
BC CD CF

CD
CF
CD CF
```

I recommend you to replace `None` with `''` or remove them.

Comment: Yessss!!! This is the sort of thing I was after. Nice one. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your welcome, if you find this correct please consider upvote and accept the answer. thakns

Comment: @fred.schwartz I added a little update there. check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, to express

```
all_others=[CD,CF,CG]  #All, 1, 2 or none of these
```

break it up as

```
all_others=[CD]  #one or none of these
all_others=[CF]  #one or none of these
all_others=[CG]  #one or none of these
```

Then your code becomes

```
from itertools import product

for choices in product(['AA','AS','AD',None],['BB', 'BC', None], ['CD', None], ['CF', None], ['CG', None],):
    print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))
```

This handles this particular example.
However, if you instead have several items starting with C, they can be handled more systematically as follows:

```
from itertools import product

for choices in product(['AA','AS','AD',None],['BB', 'BC', None], *product(['CD', 'CF', 'CG'], [None]),):
    print(' '.join(column for column in choices if column))
```

To explain what's going on, taking the product of `['CD', 'CF', 'CG']` with `[None]` yields an iterator containing

```
('CD', None), ('CF', None), ('CG', None)
```

These are precisely the arguments we wish to pass to `product`  The `*` operator converts the elements inside an iterator into function arguments.  Thus the above two code snippets are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, is there a more efficient way of doing this? That list of variables might get very large, and not sure I can type them all out

Comment: If I wanted to change the condition for B's, to say I must have at least 1 B present but could have more. How would I do that?